# can't be able to run query for nested fields while I have set fields in mapping as nested

Tags: elasticsearch

I can't run search query for anything that contain particular entity.
as I want to to search anything containing my string like i am searching for football then it should return me any label, keyword etc containing football.

mapping for my index is:

```
{
"properties": {
  "name": {
    "type": "text",
    "analyzer": "string_lowercase",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  },
  "faces": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
      "videoId": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "string_lowercase",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "seenDuration": {
        "type": "float",
        "analyzer": "string_lowercase",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
      "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "string_lowercase",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "appearances": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "startTime": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "string_lowercase",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "endTime": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "string_lowercase",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "startSeconds": {
            "type": "float",
            "analyzer": "string_lowercase",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "endSeconds": {
            "type": "float",
            "analyzer": "string_lowercase",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
    }
  }
}
```

and after running this query to get search result :

```
        {
       "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "faces",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                { "match": { "faces.id": "2dd83650b8" } }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }


I am getting this error:
     {
                "type": "query_shard_exception",
                "reason": "failed to create query: [nested] nested object under path [faces] is not of nested type",
                "index_uuid": "ZwuSr9IuRVKSPmCDwyaJHg",
                "index": "indexer4"
            }
```

kindly guide me for this ?? and suggest queries ??

Comment: @BhargavRao I'm not sure why this question was closed. Can you elaborate? The OP provided enough details to dig into the problem

Comment: @Val Feel free to check the original revision. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65019250/revisions

Comment: @BhargavRao fair enough, it's all good now, so I voted for reopening it. Thanks

Comment: @Abdul wahab khan can you please share some sample index data? And which version of elasticsearch you are using?

Comment: I think what happens is that `faces` is not `nested` even though you think it is. Can you share the "real mapping" of your index, i.e. the one you get when running `GET indexer4`